# ngx-daterangepicker-material to open with previous and current month instead of current and next month

Tags: angular, datepicker, momentjs, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I am using [ngx-daterangepicker-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material) which shows current and next month for latest range.

```
<input type="text" 
    ngxDaterangepickerMd
    [locale]="{ 'format': 'MM/DD/YYYY'}"
    [(ngModel)]="selected"
    [ranges]="ranges"
    alwaysShowCalendars="true"
    name="daterange"/>
```

Is it possible to show previous and current month?

[Stackblitz link is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ajgin?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: like this ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmmlaz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @dota2pro: For range "Today", the months displayed are Feb and Mar. If datepicker is used to select only dates before current date, then the right hand month March becomes useless as any date from it can't be selected